# How to set Unique value in mongodb using node express both uper and lower case

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Well I have already done in mongoose schema by setting my property with `unique:true` like below

`mongoose.Schema({ userName: {  type: String,  unique: true  }})`

this time i want to do it through my router api's

`User.findOne({userName: req.body.userName})`

it only works when i enter same string as save already in database.like
`userName: ranatouseef`
but if i enter `userName: ranaTouseef` it fails,
well regix don't work here like regix also have issue like that well if i search for `userName: rana` regix find it `ranatouseef`. well same goes for `touseef` to well my issu is find same string but without casesensitive,
how can i do that.

Comment: It's okay for you a solution where every userName is lowercased before saved in the database?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should set the username in lower case.

```
new User({ username: req.body.userName.toLowerCase() });
User.save()
```

And when you want retrieve it, use the `toLowerCase` method on the argument.

```
User.findOne({ userName: req.body.userName.toLowerCase() })
```

You should always avoid to duplicate your data in your DB. Here, you are about to save a string in lowercase and in uppercase. I don't know your use case but it makes no sense to me.

Also, my solution solves the issue of "RanaTouseef" and "ranaTouseef" being 2 unique username

Comment: by saving in lower case is make no sense. like client send userName like ( ranaTouseef ) mixture of upper and lower case but server change it to lower case ( ranatouseef ) then client try to check their credentials which is changed so it create mess on client side. never do megical think which low down your product quality.

Comment: When the client check, change it to lowercase before sending the request. Anyway, do it the way you want, your product quality and the energy you spend managing two fields in your DB asking question on SO are not any of my concern